# Saving form fields on custom entity

Tags: forms, entities

I'm having problems saving my custom entity to the db. I created a custom entity called 'review' using `hook_entity_info()` with a custom controller. I have specified some parameters in the controller using:

```
      public function create(array $values = array()) {
      global $user;
      $values = array(
      'rid' => '',
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'nid' => $_GET['nid'],
      'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'changed' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'published' => 1,
      'quality' => '',
      'design' => '',
      'versatility' => '',
      'design' => '',
   );
   return parent::create($values);
 }
```

Everything seems to be working just fine but when I try to submit my form to create a new entity not all fields are saved in the db.

I attached the value of the fields in the form using `field_attach_form('review', $review, $form, $form_state);` and in my submit function I have this:

```
$review_submission = (object) $form_state['values'];
field_attach_submit('review', $review_submission, $form, $form_state);
$review = entity_create('review', array('type' => 'review'));
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('review',  $review);
$entity->save($review_submission); //This saves info but not fields
```

This creates a new entity but the fields `'quality', 'design', 'versatility', 'relevance'` are not saved. However if I use this instead in my submit function:

```
review_submission = (object) $form_state['values'];
field_attach_submit('review', $review_submission, $form, $form_state);
$review = entity_create('review', array('type' => 'review'));
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('review',  $review);
entity_get_controller('review')->save($review_submission); //This saves fields but not info
```

those fields are correctly saved BUT then `'rid', 'uid', 'nid', 'created', 'changed', 'published'` are not saved.

What am I missing? How can I saved the entity info and the values from the form fields?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to provide these values manually before the save, for example:

```
$entity->created = isset($entity->is_new) ? REQUEST_TIME : $entity->created;
$entity->changed = REQUEST_TIME;
$entity->uid = $user->uid;
```

or copy them directly from `$form_state['values']`.

I've found [`entityFormSubmit`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/inline_entity_form/tree/includes/entity.inline_entity_form.inc#n307) method from Inline Entity Form module which is manually copying all fields which are not fields to entity properties, so gave me the idea for this code:

```
$form_id = $form_state['build_info']['form_id'];
$entity = $form['#entity'] ?: $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
$entity_type = $entity->entityType();
$entity_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
$entity_values = drupal_array_get_nested_value($form_state['values'], $form['#parents']);
list(, , $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);

$values_excluding_fields = $info['fieldable'] ? array_diff_key($entity_values, field_info_instances($this->entityType, $bundle)) : $entity_values;
foreach ($values_excluding_fields as $key => $value) {
  $entity->$key = $value;
} 
if ($entity_info['fieldable']) {
  field_attach_submit($entity_type, $entity, $form, $form_state);
}
$entity->created = isset($entity->is_new) ? REQUEST_TIME : $entity->created;
$entity->changed = REQUEST_TIME;
entity_save($entity_type, $entity);
```